# Canny Edge detection for higher resolutions vs lower resolutions

Tags: python, opencv, canny-operator

if i want to implement an edge detection algorithm on python using opencv, should i go for an image which has 3200x2400 resolution or a 640x480? would there be a difference in the edges detected (would i get more correct edges with the higher resolution?). I also wanted to do a distance calculation using the image that i will be capturing. I wish to get a result that is as accurate as possible.

Answer (score 0):

[Canny edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector) is a method that uses gradients and thresholds to detect edges. Assuming that in both cases you would have the exact same object and you would just change the camera to get a better resolution (more pixels), then in lower resolution the contour has normally more blur and is less sharp, resulting in smaller gradient values that are less likely to be selected via thresholding. Nevertheless, there are many other parameters that will influence your result and depending on what you are imaging, the finer details due to higher resolution may not make much difference to compensate it.

Comment: I forgot to mention distance calculation. You should get more precise results by having smaller pixels (higher resolution), but again it depends on your application and its limitations.

Comment: thanks for your answer! i have to take a top view image of two walls in a baking furnace and i have to calculate the distance between their edges. Using OpenCV on the raspberry pi, i wanted to stream the pi camera view but i cant do that with higher res because the fps drops and the pi gets heated up. So i thought of streaming the lower res view and capturing images on high res. What you said makes sense, i think ill go with higher res for the distance calculation. Thank you!